# Javascript/PHP JSON Array null in IE

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Hi I have a javascript code that connects to a php script via ajax. This php script returns an array. In the success function of the ajax call, I use the returned array to display information to the user. This all works fine in all the browsers I have tried except Internet Explorer. I get the following error:

```
Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
```

'0' is the index of the first element in the array. Here is the code:

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/add.php",
    data: 'id=' + itemid,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data[0];
        document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = data[1];
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = data[2];
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
$output = array();
$output[0] = $itemname;
$output[1] = $itemdescription;
$output[2] = $itemprice;
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
```

I tried `console.log(data)` in the success function and in Internet Explorer it returns null whereas other browsers it returns the array. Does anyone know what is wrong here?

EDIT: The error code on the console in IE is SCRIPT5007. Upon searching this, this means:

```
You attempted to invoke the Object.prototype.toString or Object.prototype.valueOf method on an object of a type other than Object. The object of this type of invocation must be of type Object.
```

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-GB&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.SCRIPT5007)

Comment: Take a look at the output generated http://codepad.org/7quG3IKs

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
$output = array();
$output[] = $itemname;
$output[] = $itemdescription;
$output[] = $itemprice;
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
```

Note that `$output[]=xxx` means : append xxx to `$output` where `$output[1]=xxx` means, put xxx at index 1 of `$output`.

Note that you may as well do :

```
$output = array($itemname, $itemdescription, $itemprice);
```

EDIT for comments and multiples OP edits :

Try printing the data to see what's going on :

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data[0];
    document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = data[1];
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = data[2];
},
```

You'll see what `data` contains, for IE, in the console (use F12)

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake look at the block of code again in my question. I am adding to 3 different indexes

Comment: you need to set index 0, which you use in javascript.
So then you'll set `$output[0] = $itemname; $output[1] = $itemdescription; $output[2] = $itemprice;` Note that first index of an array is 0, not 1.

Comment: As the variables contain long strings, I didnt want to do it in one line as you suggested. I dont think the problem is with my PHP code if all the other broswers can execute it fine

Comment: As I said in the OP, I already tried console.log(data) and it returned null in IE, but other browsers it returned the array

Comment: what does the console.log() says if you remove the `datatype:json` line?

Comment: On IE it says 'undefined', on other browsers it returns the array where each element is seperated by a comma

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why, try to warp it as a kv object?

```
$output = array(
    'item' => array (
        $itemname, $itemdescription, $itemprice
    )
);
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
```